# URL prefix in Flask Python deployed to Heroku using Blueprint

Tags: python, api, flask, routes, blueprint

I'm trying to create a URL prefix for my web app's api. I want the api to return when I enter api.website.com/parameter.I am using Flask and Blueprint

```
api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__,                        
    template_folder='templates', 
    url_prefix='/api')

@api_bp.route("/")
def get_monkey_api():
    address = request.args.get('address', 
None)
    if address and is_a_banano_address(address):
        return monkey_api(banano_address)
    else:
        return render_template("NotABananoAddress.html"), 400

@api_bp.route("/<address>")
def monkey_api(address):
    monKey = monkey_data_generator.generate_monKey(address)
    if monKey.status is not 'Citizen':
        return "API data on vanity monKeys does not exist"
    return jsonify(monKey.serialize())

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')
```

Most of the code in unrelated. The fact is when I I am entering

```
api.website.com?address=xxx
```

or when I am entering

```
api.website.com/xxx
```

I should get my API as JSON back but I'm not. On localhost it doesn't return anything and doesn't show the prints that I even insert into the code and of course on Heroku it does not recognize the project when I using the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You gave your blueprint a *URL prefix*:

```
api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__,                        
    template_folder='templates', 
    url_prefix='/api')
```

and again with

```
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')
```

That means you need to use `hostname/api/` to get to `get_monkey_api()` view function, or `hostname/api/xxxx` to get to the `monkey_api()` view function.

Remove the URL prefixes if you want the routes to be found at the site root. If you want the blueprint to work for a separate subdomain, then use the `subdomain='api'` option, not a URL prefix.

Note that for subdomains to work, you need to configure the [`SERVER_NAME` config option](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#SERVER_NAME) so that subdomains can be detected. If you want to test this locally, edit your `/etc/hosts` file to add some development aliases that point to your server, then set `SERVER_NAME` to match.

Comment: If i never tell the app that the prefix for this blueprint is api how could it now I want this to display at api.hostname.com? Right now you are correct, it works with api/xx or api?address=xxx but this I can do without the blueprints. I wants the API to be on the prefix. how can I do this? thanks

Comment: @Randomizer: that's not a clear question. Is `api.hostname.com` a *seprate domain name*? Then set the `subdomain` option, not a URL prefix!

Comment: I think I mixed both. I guess I want this as a subdomain. Just when I write api.hostname.com an insert an input it will give me its json metadata. I've changed to registration to app.register_blueprint(api_bp, subdomain='/api')
but it doesn't work still

Comment: Do read the relevant documentation; `subdomain` matching requires that `SERVER_NAME` is set so that the sub domain can be detected.